# How to display full datetime in pandas when time is 00:00:00 for the complete column in jupyter/html

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook

If a full column is exactly 00:00:00 time pandas will display the dataframe column without time. For my use-case this could be confusing to the user as to what is actually in the column (date vs datetime).

Below a reproducible example with 2 columns one with and without exact 00:00:00.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([
        (datetime(2021,10,3,0,0,0), datetime(2021,10,3,1,1,1)),
        (datetime(2021,10,3,0,0,0), datetime(2021,10,3,1,1,1)),
])

df
```

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl0Tf.png)

`df.values` (below) are still there, so I'm I need to add a date display parser/formatter somehow.

```
array([['2021-10-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2021-10-03T01:01:01.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2021-10-03T01:01:01.000000000']],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

The direct use of `df.to_html()` (I guess used in the jupyter repr) produces the following html table.

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>2021-10-03</td>
      <td>2021-10-03 01:01:01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2021-10-03</td>
      <td>2021-10-03 01:01:01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using the style renderer produces the wanted result (below). However I'd like it to correctly display using just the general notebook cell representation. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

HTML_string = df.style.render()

display(HTML(HTML_string))
```

Comment: you could create a string dtype column from the datetime column; `.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` for example

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This would change the dtype of the column, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: To be more precise, I meant to create a *new* column of dtype string, just for display. For actual data handling, you'd still have the datetime column.